# Getting data from selected range to a field in an excel form (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: vb.net, excel, forms, vba, visual-studio

I'm trying to implement a user form in Excel using Visual Studio 2015.

I'm looking for a way to get the value from a selected area (range), instantly when the user selects it (without clicking on a button for example).

Have you any ideas? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use vba inside Excel to create the form and operate on the range if need be rather than Visual Studio?  Either way, check out the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event in VBA help; should provide exactly what you need

Comment: I support Dave's comment, and have an additional question: Is this a VSTO solution?

Comment: Yes Cindy Meister! I try to perform a VSTO solution using visual studio. I can't find a way to implement what I want.

Comment: You can hook into the Excel application events and monitor the sheet `SelectionChange` event.  Eg: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/266bc8c8-15f6-47d7-9927-c31c3625e48e/event-handler-for-excel-activesheet-selectionchange-c?forum=vsto

Answer (score 0):

Or just create a shortcut key to call the subroutine in your excel macros.

once your subroutine/function is created

go to developers tab > Macros > choose your macro in the list > click options > enter a shortcut key.

Once done click ok and test your subroutine by pressing Ctrl + letter that you chose

**ATTENTION: do not use shortcut keys that already exist like:

Ctrl + A (select all)
or
Ctrl + s (save)

etc...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for answering! What I am seeking is not adding a macro in Excel but building something like a refedit control: http://ericrenaud.fr/refedit.htm

Thank you for the precious help!